# Adding multiple instances of the same fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I am attempting to add multiple instances of the same fragment to an activity. Example code is

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content);

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    for (int x = 1; x < 5; x = x + 1) {
        Log.i("frag","x="+x);
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, new SpecimenFragment(),"x_"+x);           
    }

    ft.commit();
```

When the activity runs there is only one instance of the fragment added - why?

For info the fragments are being inserted into an XML layout for the activity and the 
R.id.fragment_content referenced in the code is defined as :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Can you post your layout xml file that contains `R.id.fragment_content`?

Comment: Added the definition of `R.id.fragment_content` to the question

Comment: Is this supposed to be a tab style layout?

Comment: No it's not a tab layout. There are meant to be a variable number of fragments stacked vertically on the screen.

Comment: I think the issue is that I am using a FrameLayout and that there are all the fragments, it's just that they are all on top of each other. I need a way to make them not do that.

Comment: Can you show the xml you're inflating in `onCreateView` of `SpecimenFragment()`? Do you have ids in that layout? Compiler doesn't show `Duplicate id with another fragment` when inflating all 5 fragments in same activity/layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seemed to be is using the `FrameLayout` as the container for the fragments. I change this to

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

and it now works fine.