# How to inflate multiple instances of same fragment in activity (gmap)?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I've checked around and I see no one has asked exactly the question, since what people are doing is replacing fragments to show them one moment or another. Except [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349816/adding-multiple-instances-of-the-same-fragment) who loaded 5 fragments of same instance inside a `LinearLayout`.

What I'm trying to do is really simple, I want one activity that shows me 3 fragments (instances of same class, that inflate same layout).

Everytime I instance my custom `Fragment` class I was inflating one xml with a `<fragment/>` that loads a map. At start, compiler told me `Duplicate id with another fragment` because that `<fragment/>` had same id in all 3 Fragments (it was the same xml being inflated).

So I replaced `<fragment/>` to `<FrameLayout/>` (same id again), and loaded the map dynamically. I was expecting same error, but it didn't happen, issue is, it only shows first map (in third of the screen) and the other Fragments show nothing.

What can I do to have in screen 3 maps, each of one in different fragment?

Pdt: I've already tried loading maps with different tags, one per fragment. Didn't work.

## EDIT

I just tried something, having in mind the issue was with the IDs. What I tried was adding an attribute to my custom class, `int mapId`, and I set it after instantiating the fragment with ids 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

Now, in `onCreateView()` before returning the inflated view, I set the of the container `<FrameLayout/>` doing `frame.setId(frame.getId()+mapId);`... finally when loading dynamically the map in the container, I ask for the id `R.id.map+mapId`. And well, it worked:

[image: Screenshot, same Fragment class, 3 different instances]

Is that an acceptable or recommendable practice? pros/cons? What are the odds that modifying manually an id, it causes a conflict with another existing auto-generated ID?