# Multiple instances of the same fragment?

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am making an Android app with Visual Studio and C#. I know I should porbably use Java, but I prefer C#, so I chose to use that. But anyway, I have a problem where I can't add the same fragment twice. I know this is a duplicate, but **none of the other questions helped at all.** Here is one I looked at:[Adding multiple instances of the same fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349816/adding-multiple-instances-of-the-same-fragment)

All of my code is pretty much the same, except only one fragment gets added. Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    var trans = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        trans.Add(Resource.Id.bottomLayout, new BottomFragment(), "Fragment_" + i.ToString());

    trans.Commit();
}
```

Resource.Id.bottomLayout is a vertical LinearLayout, so I have no idea what the problem is. I feel like everyone will just get all mad because it's a duplicate(because that always happens to me, which is why I use this site as a last resort), but if I could receive some help, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that all five fragments are directly on top of each other.

Apply an `android:orientation="vertical"` or `android:orientation="vertical"` to your LinearLayout in order to get them to expand the `LinearLayout`:

#### Vertical:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" />
```

#### Horizontal:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I thought it was too, but that wasn't the case. Here is my layout:
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout" />

Comment: @KyleStankovich You are using `match_parent` for both the width and height, and thus all five fragments are on top of each other. Try using one of the layouts that are in my answer and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Omg thank you SO much man. I can't believe it was that easy lol. Thank you so freaking much.